# AngularJS: calling $watchGroup from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I call $watctGroup form link function of directive. I've got two simple scope elements (integer)  and I'd like to watch them in pair. I suppose $watchGroup is more effective than to use something like $watch('[element1, element2'],..).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
scope.element1=1;
scope.element2=2;
scope.$watchGroup(['element1','element2'], function(){/* your code here */});
```

### Update:

Bare in mind that `$watchGroup` started being available in AngularJS 1.3, if you are using a previous version it won't work.

Example of how to use `$watchGroup` in a directive:

```
angular.module ('testApp' , [])
.directive ('testDirective', function (){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div ng-click="inc()">{{element1}} <br/> {{element2}}</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.element1=0;
            scope.element2=0;
            scope.inc = function(){scope.element1++;scope.element2--};
            scope.$watchGroup(['element1', 'element2'], function(){
                console.log('something changed!');
            });
        }
    }
 });
```

### [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ATAWTqVVlwBMnuQHsH5B?p=preview)

Comment: Nope. It will not work. I've got not $scope but scope (parameter). Angular says that method watchGroup doesn't defined on scope.

Comment: @user1795707 both: '$watch' and '$watchGroup' are public methods of $scope, you can only $watch properties from the scope. Make sure that in the link function of your directive you are getting the scope in the first parameter.

Comment: @user1795707 sorry, there was a typo in my answer, please try it again.

Comment: @user1795707 I've made another update, please have a look at it. I think that your problem is that you are using < Angularjs 1.3, and $watchGroup was not available until AngularJs 1.3.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! Indeed I've got AngularJS v1.2.24

Comment: @user1795707 I'm glad that this helped you, any time!